# Magento change index mode using command line

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, command-line

I need to change index mode for a particular single index using command line.

I have followed [this link](http://inchoo.net/magento/executing-magento-indexer-from-shell/) it allows me to re-index data but when I try to change mode of index, either I get list of available options or get all of the indexes mode changed.

If I run below command,

```
php -f shell/indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_url
```

it changes mode for all indexes instead of changing mode only for `catalog_url`

If I run below command,

```
php -f shell/indexer.php catalog_url --mode-realtime
```

I get list of options and mode for index is not changed.
Can anyone suggest what to do to change mode for a single index using command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below command to change mode for your index.

```
php -f shell/indexer.php -- --mode-realtime catalog_url
```

If you want to change mode for multiple indexes, use comma separated values.

```
php -f shell/indexer.php -- --mode-realtime catalog_url,catalog_product_flat
```